# ASP.Net GridView RowUpdate not firing and RowUpdating doesn't have NewValues

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, gridview, datatable

I have the following GridView:

```cs
<asp:GridView ID="gridCar" runat="server" RowStyle-ForeColor="Black" AllowSorting="true" OnSorting="gridCar_Sorting" AutoGenerateEditButton="true" OnRowEditing="gridCar_RowEditing" OnRowCancelingEdit="gridCar_RowCancelingEdit" OnRowUpdating="gridCar_RowUpdating" OnRowUpdated="gridCar_RowUpdated"></asp:GridView>
```

I want to update the row selected by the edit button. The problem is, if I try to do it in `gridCar_RowUpdating`, `e.NewValues` doesn't contain the edited values but the old ones instead.

I searched around and found out that I might have to use `onRowUpdated` event instead, but then I face another problem; this event isn't fired at all. I tried to set `e.Cancel = false` in `gridCar_RowUpdating` but that won't fix the issue.

The GridView is binded to a DataTable.

EDIT: Here's my code:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

using System.Data;

public partial class _Default : Page
{
    DataTable carsTable = new DataTable("cars");

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            carsTable.Columns.Add("CarID");
            carsTable.Columns.Add("CarRegNum");
            carsTable.Columns.Add("CarModel");
            carsTable.Columns.Add("CarType");
            carsTable.Columns.Add("CarOwner");

            carsTable.Rows.Add(1, "AAA-111", "Toyota", "Hatchback", "Matti");
            carsTable.Rows.Add(2, "BBB-222", "Mercedes-Benz", "Van", "Keijo");
            carsTable.Rows.Add(3, "CCC-333", "Renault", "Regular", "Matilda");

            carsTable.AcceptChanges();

            gridCar.DataSource = carsTable;
            gridCar.DataBind();
        }
    }

    protected string dataViewSortDirection(SortDirection direction)
    {
        switch (direction)
        {
            case SortDirection.Ascending:
                return "ASC";
            case SortDirection.Descending:
                return "DESC";
            default:
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        }
    }

    protected void gridCar_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
    {
        gridCar.Sort(e.SortExpression, e.SortDirection);

        // update GridView
        gridCar.DataBind();
    }

    protected void gridCar_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        gridCar.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        gridCar.DataBind();
    }

    protected void gridCar_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
    {
        gridCar.EditIndex = -1;
        gridCar.DataBind();
    }

    protected void gridCar_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        labelDebug.Text += "b";
        //gridCar.EditIndex = -1;
        //gridCar.DataBind();
    }

    protected void gridCar_RowUpdated(object sender, GridViewUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        labelDebug.Text += "a";
        gridCar.EditIndex = -1;
        gridCar.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: Storing datatable in ViewState is not a good practice as it increases the size of your page and reduces the performance, also ViewState can be deciphered on the client side, so the DataTable is not secure.

Comment: @TimSchmelter What would you suggest I do instead in my case?

Comment: As commented on my answer, you don't need to persist the datasource since the data is stored in the GridView's ViewState anyway. So `e.OldValues` and `e.NewValues` are set even if you don't transport your `DataTable` from server to client and back to the server. But you need to ensure that it get's databound only on the first load(`!IsPostBack`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you sure that you don't databind the `GridView` on postbacks? You should do that only `if(!IsPostBack)`:

```
protected void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        BindGridView();
    }
}
```

Otherwise you are loading the old values and prevent the `RowUpdated` event.

**Update**

> I'm probably doing a lot of things wrong, can you show me how I
>   should do sorting and updating now?

Here's a complete working sample:

```
public partial class GridTest : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            BindGrid();
        }
    }

    private void BindGrid()
    {
        var source = GetCarTable().Select("", this.SortExpression).CopyToDataTable();
        GridCar.DataSource = source;
        GridCar.DataBind();
    }

    private string SortExpression
    {
        get
        {
            if (ViewState["SortExpression"] == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty((String)ViewState["SortExpression"]))
            {
                ViewState["SortExpression"] = "CarModel ASC";
            }
            return ViewState["SortExpression"].ToString();
        }
        set { ViewState["SortExpression"] = value; }
    }

    private static DataTable GetCarTable()
    {
        DataTable carsTable = new DataTable("cars");
        carsTable.Columns.Add("CarID");
        carsTable.Columns.Add("CarRegNum");
        carsTable.Columns.Add("CarModel");
        carsTable.Columns.Add("CarType");
        carsTable.Columns.Add("CarOwner");

        carsTable.Rows.Add(1, "AAA-111", "Toyota", "Hatchback", "Matti");
        carsTable.Rows.Add(2, "BBB-222", "Mercedes-Benz", "Van", "Keijo");
        carsTable.Rows.Add(3, "CCC-333", "Renault", "Regular", "Matilda");

        return carsTable;
    }

    protected void gridCar_Sorting(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewSortEventArgs e)
    {
        string currentSortColumn = null;
        string currentSortDirection = null;
        currentSortColumn = this.SortExpression.Split(' ')[0];
        currentSortDirection = this.SortExpression.Split(' ')[1];

        if (e.SortExpression.Equals(currentSortColumn))
        {
            //switch sort direction
            switch (currentSortDirection.ToUpper())
            {
                case "ASC":
                    this.SortExpression = currentSortColumn + " DESC";
                    break;
                case "DESC":
                    this.SortExpression = currentSortColumn + " ASC";
                    break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            this.SortExpression = e.SortExpression + " ASC";
        }

        //load the data with this SortExpression and DataBind the Grid
        BindGrid();
    }

    protected void GridCar_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        GridCar.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        BindGrid();
    }

    protected void GridCar_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
    {
        GridCar.EditIndex = -1;
        BindGrid();
    }

    protected void GridCar_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        var oldValues = e.OldValues;
        var newValues = e.NewValues;
        // BindGrid();
    }

    protected void GridCar_RowUpdated(object sender, GridViewUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        //BindGrid();
    }
}
```

aspx remains nearly unchanged:

```
<asp:GridView   ID="GridCar" 
            runat="server" 
            RowStyle-ForeColor="Black" 
            AllowSorting="true" 
            OnSorting="gridCar_Sorting" 
            AutoGenerateEditButton="true" 
            OnRowEditing="GridCar_RowEditing"
            OnRowCancelingEdit="GridCar_RowCancelingEdit"
            OnRowUpdating="GridCar_RowUpdating" 
            OnRowUpdated="GridCar_RowUpdated"
            AutoGenerateColumns="true">
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: I edited the opening post with my `Page_Load`. I doubt it's the problem since my sorting works perfectly fine, although I did have to build a workaround for e.SortDirection because it was always ascending.

Comment: Don't store your `DataTable` in ViewState, that is insecure and very ineffcient. You don't need to transport the table since `gridView` stores it's data in ViewState by default anyway. My answer remains, you have to wrap the databinding in a `!PostBack`-check.

Comment: I removed everything I did with ViewState and edited the original post again with what I currently got. Difference is that now nothing works anymore. I cannot sort the GridView because I'm trying to sort with `gridCar.Sort` in `gridCar_Sorting` which causes a stack overflow. I'm probably doing a lot of things wrong, can you show me how I should do sorting and updating now?

Comment: Great it works! A small follow up question though: can I manipulate the data in GridView directly or do I have to make a DataTable out of it's DataSource then edit it and rebind?

Comment: You can edit the data in the GridView, but then yiou have to update the DataSource, in this case the in-memory DataTable. I thought that this was just a sampleand that you're actually using a database. Where do you want to store the data?

Comment: I don't need to store the data permanently anywhere. I don't want the client to store the whole DataTable (as I guess using ViewState did?) but rather that the server stores it and the client can see and edit it. So I'm guessing session in this case?

Comment: @Kyto: Then you should use the Session to store the DataTable.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't have DataSourceID. I assume the data binding is at the Code Behind.

If you just want to edit/update the row of the GridView, what you need is the **ItemUpdating** event (for example **gridcar_ItemUpdating**) and *not RowUpdating*.

I hope it helps you.

Comment: Do those events even exist for GridView? I can't find them from `<asp:GridView></asp:GridView>`.

Comment: Oh, my mistake. I thought it's DetailsView. Tim's answer is the better approach to solve your problem.